# digital signature on image and text

Tags: signature

i am trying to implement an android app that should "sign" an image, M and a string, S using a private key, K<sup>-1</sup> and send the result to a server.

for instance the app should be doing {M,S}<sub>K<sup>-1</sup></sub>.

the content must remain separate after the server remove the { }<sub>K<sup>-1</sup></sub> barrier

the question is should some sort of file or datatype that can be used for this?

Answer (score 2):

A common way to sign things is the Digital Signature Algorithm. It will create a signature using the private key and some message.

Comment: In this answer "message" can be any bitstring including an image or text.  It might seem silly to state, but I'm frequently baffled to discover people asking questions about how to encrypt __insert data format here__ separately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to send a ["detached signature"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/detached_signature) from your android app to your server.
It sounds like you want to know "What is the standard file format for containing detached signature data?".
There are several standard formats for such "detached signature" data:

- The ["Detached signatures"](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html#AEN160) section of the "Making and verifying signatures" section of "The GNU Privacy Handbook" demonstrates using `gpg` to create a "detached signature ... using the `--detach-sig` option."
- [RFC5485](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5485) describes one way to "create a detached signature, which is stored in a separate companion file", using [Cryptographic Message Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) (CMS) defined in [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652).
- [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) signatures are usually "detached signatures". MIME and S/MIME also describes one way of bundling some plain text, arbitrary attachments, and a S/MIME signature covering all that data, into a single message. (It also uses the same Cryptographic Message Syntax).
- [XML Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Signature) describes one way to store a detached signature in a XML file. The XML Signature standards also describe one way to bundle some plain text, arbitrary data or links to arbitrary data, and a signature covering all that data, into single message.
- The [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) standard defines a (less frequently used) mode that, in addition to authenticating all the data from the server to your android app, also authenticates (signs) all data from your Android app to the server using a private key known only to that Android device. (You probably already use TLS in the most common mode, which authenticates (signs) all data from the server to the web browser when you visit a "https://" URL, but doesn't authenticate any data in the other direction).
- (Other standard formats for detached signatures?)